# SOAP POST requests

Tags: xml, web-services, go, soap

I have to integrate SOAP API using Go,

Code I tried without structs
https://gist.github.com/zaynkorai/b612c527f85c43c18fa878ef2a0e4b0e

Example Request data looks like this one,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hps="http://Hps.Exchange.PosGateway">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <hps:PosRequest>
            <hps:Ver1.0>
                <hps:Header>
                    <hps:LicenseId>${#Project#LicenseID-Retail}</hps:LicenseId>
                    <hps:SiteId>${#Project#SiteID-Retail}</hps:SiteId>
                    <hps:DeviceId>${#Project#DeviceID-Retail}</hps:DeviceId>
                    <hps:UserName>${#Project#UserName-Retail}</hps:UserName>
                    <hps:Password>${#Project#Password}</hps:Password>
                    <hps:SiteTrace>${#Project#SiteTrace}</hps:SiteTrace>
                    <hps:DeveloperID>${#Project#DeveloperID}</hps:DeveloperID>
                    <hps:VersionNbr>${#Project#VersionNbr}</hps:VersionNbr>
                    <hps:ClerkID>${#Project#ClerkID}</hps:ClerkID>
                </hps:Header>
                <hps:Transaction>
                    <hps:CreditSale>
                        <hps:Block1>
                            <hps:CardData>
                                <hps:TrackData method="swipe">${#Project#VISA_EMV_TRACK2}</hps:TrackData>
                            </hps:CardData>
                            <hps:Amt>25.00</hps:Amt>
                            <hps:AllowDup>Y</hps:AllowDup>
                            <hps:TagData>
                                <hps:TagValues source="chip">${#Project#VISA_EMV_TAGS_ONLINE}</hps:TagValues>
                            </hps:TagData>
                        </hps:Block1>
                    </hps:CreditSale>
                </hps:Transaction>
            </hps:Ver1.0>
        </hps:PosRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: And for each one: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Edited the post to 1 question. added code as well, But I want to achieve it using structs.
I tried using `https://github.com/tiaguinho/gosoap` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Creating Go struct definitions for an API is a common issue. The SOAP WSDL artifact defines the API so a translation tool can be built to convert SOAP WSDL to Go structs.

There are some existing tools that auto-generate Go structs from a SOAP WSDL file, so you don't have to create them by hand as you are doing. Information for some existing tools is provided below. If existing tools don't meet your needs, code generation is still the approach to use to create structs at scale, but you may need to look into either enhancing an existing tool or building your own.

When working with complex APIs where you just need to perform a small set of operations, a smaller Go definition may be more efficient to implement. You can either define just the APIs and properties you need, or not create any structs and generically parse the XML for your needs.

### github.com/hooklift/gowsdl

This is a more popular CLI tool with 881 GitHub stars and the following syntax. It also supports Go Modules.

```
Usage: gowsdl [options] myservice.wsdl
  -o string
        File where the generated code will be saved (default "myservice.go")
  -p string
        Package under which code will be generated (default "myservice")
  -i    Skips TLS Verification
  -v    Shows gowsdl version
```

Project repo: https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl

### github.com/fiorix/wsdl2go

This is an alternate CLI tool with 402 GitHub stars and the following syntax. It has not been updated to Go Modules yet and uses `dep` for dependency management.

```
Usage: wsdl2go < file.wsdl > hello.go
```

Project repo: https://github.com/fiorix/wsdl2go

### github.com/droyo/go-xml

This tool has 224 GitHub stars and uses Go Modules.

The author writes:

> This code is still very rough around the edges, but I have succesfully used it to generate type declarations for some pretty complex XML schema from an Apache Axis application.

Project repo: https://github.com/droyo/go-xml

Comment: Thanks, but these tools didn't helped much just provided basic structs.

Comment: If you don't want to create a lot fo structs by hand, code generation is the approach to use. Since these don't meet your needs, a more efficient approach than creating by hand is to (a) update an existing tool or (b) build your own tool. My team has done both for REST APIs: contribute to existing code generation tools and built our own from scratch.